# Convert sha256 digest to UUID in python

Tags: python, hash, uuid, sha256

Given a sha256 hash of a `str` in python:

```
import hashlib

hash = hashlib.sha256('foobar'.encode('utf-8'))
```

**How can the `hash` be converted to a `UUID`?**

Note: there will obviously be a many-to-one mapping of hexdigest to UUID given that a hexdigest has `2^256` possible values and a UUID has `2^128`.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Did you try using https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The `UUID` library takes in a hex string of length 32 while sha256 hexdigest is length 64.

Comment: Hash the value using a 32 character hash, like, shudder, MD5…?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that `UUID` takes a 32 hex character input string and `hexdigest` produces 64 characters, a simple approach would be to sub-index the resulting hash digest to achieve the appropriate string length:

```
import hashlib
import uuid


hash = hashlib.sha256('foobar'.encode('utf-8'))

uuid.UUID(hash.hexdigest()[::2])
```

Comment: Is there any reason to take every other char rather than slicing the first half, i.e. `hash.hexdigest()[:16]`?

Comment: @Garrett I don't think so, I was mostly trying to best highlight the half length.

Comment: Just a note: `hash.hexdigest()[:16]` **will not work**. As said in the answer *UUID takes a 32 hex character input string and hexdigest produces 64 characters*.
You should instead use `hash.hexdigest()[:32]`, since hexdigest is 64 chars.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a KDF hash of it first which allows you to choose the desired length of bytes in the hash to fit it into a UUID.

```py
import hashlib
import uuid

uuid.UUID(bytes=hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b'foobar', b'', 10**6, dklen=16))
```

If this solution works for you, you should determine if a 16-byte KDF compromises any of your security requirements. And, you might want to use a salt too (the third argument to `pbkdf2_hmac`).