# Is it feasible to use 32 characters (128 bits) of a sha256 digest as a UUID?

Tags: python, hash, probability

I am using the following code in python to generate a deterministic UUID. I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63707085).

```
import hashlib
import uuid


hash = hashlib.sha256('foobar'.encode('utf-8'))

uuid.UUID(hash.hexdigest()[::2])
```

I can see that it is using a slice operator to get every other hexadecimal nibble. This is done because UUID() expects a 32 character long string. Effectively, this would produce 2^128 unique hashes rather than 2^256.

For my purposes, there would be at most 1 billion unique records.

Using the following approximate formula for accidental collision probability:

```
k^2/2n where:
k is the number of records (1 billion)
n is the number of total possible hashes (2^128).
```

The probability of collision is: 1.47 x 10^-21. It is low enough that I feel safe that a collision would not occur.

Anyways, I just wanted to see if anyone could confirm my above logic/intuition. Am I safe to assume that the above probability of collision for the above code is correct? Thank you.

Also, does taking every other hex nibble, instead of truncating the first/last 32 characters affect collision probability?

Note:
Apparently UUIDv5 uses a very similar technique, instead using SHA-1 as the hashing algorithm and `digest()` instead of `hexdigest()`. That leads me to believe that the above code is safe to use, but I would still like to make sure just in case [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3db42fc5aca320b0cac1895bc3cb731235ede794/Lib/uuid.py#L718).

```
def uuid5(namespace, name):
     """Generate a UUID from the SHA-1 hash of a namespace UUID and a name."""
     from hashlib import sha1
     hash = sha1(namespace.bytes + bytes(name, "utf-8")).digest()
     return UUID(bytes=hash[:16], version=5)
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a 128-bit algorithm like MD5 directly?

Comment: @tripleee Not in particular, it was just the first answer I found regarding "deterministic UUID's". This was before I even realized UUIDv5 was a thing.

Since it's not for any security purposes, I suppose that MD5 works as well. But in any case, the above code is what I have been using for a couple months.

Comment: What are the things that you are hashing? If there is a repeat in those then there'll be a repeat in the UUID.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The input strings will always be unique. Therefore, the only thing I'm concerned about is the chance of accidental collision upon hashing.

Comment: Then yes, the chances of a collision are as you have estimated, vanishingly small.